# Web parts cause Navigation styling issues

Tags: navigation

I am using a Content Editor Web Part on an .ASPX page.  When I link to a document for the data source (vs type the text directly into the web part), the top and left nav items as well as the ribbon all take on an underline for that page only.  Removing the web part or typing the text directly into the web part resolves the issue.  I've tried saving the source document in a number of formats (htm, html, doc) but get the same results.

Any ideas what is causing this?